# Loop "FOR" to iterate through list in class

Tags: python, list, loops, class

I'm trying to create a loop to print data from all people in list.
I have created:

```
Class –> event
List –> list
Function –> dane

class event:
def __init__(self, imie, nazwisko, firma, stanowisko, mail):
    self.imie =  imie
    self.nazwisko = nazwisko
    self.firma = firma
    self.stanowisko = stanowisko
    self.mail = mail

JagodaSobczak = event(imie="Jagoda", nazwisko="Sobczak")
DitaKowalska = event(imie="Dita", nazwisko="Kowalska")
JaromirOstrowski = event(imie="Jaromir", nazwisko="Ostrowski")
MakaryKalinowski = event(imie="Makary", nazwisko="Kalinowski")
DrugiSzczepański= event(imie="Drugi", nazwisko="Szczepanski")

list = ["JagodaSobczak", "DitaKowalska", "JaromirOstrowski", "MakaryKalinowski", 
"DrugiSzczepański"]
```

The function works, but I need to enter its argument.
For example: data(JagodaSobczak).

```
def dane(name):
    print(name.imie, name.nazwisko)
dane(JagodaSobczak)
```

I want to create loop for to get data from a list and print class information for it.
Repeat the whole process as many times as there are arguments in the list - in this case 5 times.
Repeat can by done by len(list), but I'm stuck on creating a loop.

I created loop and I tried:

```
for i in list:
x = next(list_iterator)
dane(x) / dane(i)
```

Comment: `list` is a builtin datatype and shouldn't be assigned as a variable.

Comment: As per the actual question, are you okay with storing the classes in a list or do you need to store strings of their names?

Answer (score 1):

If you intentionally made list contain string representations of the object names as opposed to the objects themselves, then you need to use use globals() to access the actual objects:

```
list = ["JagodaSobczak", "DitaKowalska", "JaromirOstrowski", "MakaryKalinowski", 
"DrugiSzczepański"]
```

```
for i in list:
 dane(globals()[i])
```

Otherwise, if you have no reason to keep track of these names as strings, you can make it more simple:

```
list = [JagodaSobczak, DitaKowalska, JaromirOstrowski, MakaryKalinowski, 
DrugiSzczepański]
```

Then your loop will look something like:

```
for i in list:
 dane(i)
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Person:
    imie: str
    nazwisko: str
    firma: Optional[str]
    stanowisko: Optional[str]
    mail: Optional[str]

    def dane(self):
        print(self.imie, self.nazwisko)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Instantiate the people
    people = (
        Person(imie="Jagoda", nazwisko="Sobczak"),
        Person(imie="Dita", nazwisko="Kowalska"),
        Person(imie="Jaromir", nazwisko="Ostrowski"),
        Person(imie="Makary", nazwisko="Kalinowski"),
        Person(imie="Drugi", nazwisko="Szczepanski")
    )
    for person in people:
        person.dane()
```